# ENTRYPOINT without docker run

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an executable that's containerized and I use the entry point statement in the `Dockerfile`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["s10cmd"]
```

However, this is a statistical app that needs to receive a data file, so I cannot use `docker run`. Instead I create the container using `docker create` and then `docker cp` to copy the dat file into the container. However, none of the `docker` commands except run allow me to call the container as an executable.

Should I in this case, not specify `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`, and just do `docker start`, `docker exec s10cmd /tmp/data.dat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker images are just like templates , and Docker containers are live running machines.

In order to execute any commands - it requires a container , so you need to create a container , when you start the container, your entry-point will launch the command and then container will close automatically.

```
#>docker create <-- This will create an instance of the docker image
#>docker cp     <-- Copy the relevant file into the container
#>docker start  <-- Start the container entrypoint will do rest of the job.
```

Comment: Additionally you don't need a Dockerfile just to specify ENTRYPOINT.
You can create the container from the base image and launch the command in that running container.

Comment: But I don't want to hardcode the file path. After `docker start`, how can I pass in the data file?

Comment: So this such case you can mount the external file to the container so that it's available in runtime (where s10cmd command is expecting to find or you can pass this argument in the command itself). Check for how to mount external FS to docker container. https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/